# AVAssetExportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler block not executed in ios

Tags: ios, video, ios7.1, avassetexportsession

I am doing a video app in which I have to add an overlay over the image and then taking its video.I had my app working last month using iOS 7.0.But after updating when I checked it today I found that the AVAssetExportSession  exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler block is not executing.The control returns from `[exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{` line.

**Code:**

```
-(void)saving_Edited_Video

{

    AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];



    NSMutableArray *loTempArr = [[[Database sharedDBDetails] getAllUserDetails:kaudioTable] mutableCopy];

    TempFile *lotemp1 = [[TempFile alloc] init];

    TempFile *loTemp2 = [[TempFile alloc] init];

    loTemp2 = [mallVideoArray objectAtIndex:self.slectedVideoIndex];

    for (int i = 0; i < [loTempArr count]; i++)

    {

        lotemp1 = [loTempArr objectAtIndex:i];

        if (loTemp2.mTemp_Key == [lotemp1.mTemp_videorefID intValue])

        {

            //NSLog(@"%@",lotemp1.mTemp_AudioName);

            NSString *filepath = [kDocument_Path stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/audioFolder/%@",lotemp1.mTemp_AudioName]];

            NSURL    *SongURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];

            self.audioAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:SongURL options:nil];



            CMTime time2=CMTimeMake([lotemp1.mTemp_timeinvideo doubleValue]*600, 600);

            AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionCommentaryTrack2 = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

            [compositionCommentaryTrack2 insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeSubtract(self.videoAsset.duration, time2))



                                                 ofTrack:[[self.audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:time2 error:nil];

        }

    }



    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

    [compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, self.videoAsset.duration)



                                   ofTrack:[[self.videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];



    // 3.1 - Create AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction



    AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *mainInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];

    mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, self.videoAsset.duration);



   // 3.2 - Create an AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction for the video track and fix the orientation.



    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *videolayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:compositionVideoTrack];

    AVAssetTrack *videoAssetTrack = [[self.videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];



    CGSize sizeflip;

    if(flipActionFlag == 4 || flipActionFlag == 5)

    {

        sizeflip = CGSizeMake(videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.height, videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.width);

    }

    else

    {

        sizeflip = videoAssetTrack.naturalSize;

    }



    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;//



    //rotate up



    if (flipActionFlag == 2)

    {

        transform = videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform;

    }

    else if (flipActionFlag == 0)

    {

            //vertical flip

        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0.0f, sizeflip.height);

        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0f, -1.0f);

    }

    else if (flipActionFlag == 1)

    {

        //horizental flip......

        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, sizeflip.width, 0.0f);

        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0f, 1.0f);

    }

    else if (flipActionFlag == 3)

    {

        //rotate down

        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, sizeflip.width, sizeflip.height);

        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);

    }

    else if (flipActionFlag == 4)

    {

        //rotate right

        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, sizeflip.width, 0.0f);

        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI_2);

    }

    else if (flipActionFlag == 5)

    {

        //    //rotate left

        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0.0f, sizeflip.height);

        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, -M_PI_2);

    }



    [videolayerInstruction setTransform:transform atTime:kCMTimeZero];

    [videolayerInstruction setOpacity:0.0 atTime:self.videoAsset.duration];





    // 3.3 - Add instructions

  AVMutableVideoComposition *mainCompositionInst = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];

    mainInstruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:videolayerInstruction,nil];



    float renderWidth, renderHeight;

    renderWidth = self.movieController.view.frame.size.width;

    renderHeight = self.movieController.view.frame.size.height;

    CGSize size;

    if(flipActionFlag == 4 || flipActionFlag == 5)

    {

        size = CGSizeMake(videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.height, videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.width);

    }

    else

    {

        size = videoAssetTrack.naturalSize;

    }

    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGSize(size));

    mainCompositionInst.renderSize = size;//size//CGSizeMake(renderWidth, renderHeight)

    mainCompositionInst.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:mainInstruction];

    mainCompositionInst.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);



    if ([self.drawImage.lines count] > 0)

    {

        //mainCompositionInst.renderSize = CGSizeMake(renderWidth, renderHeight);

        [self applyVideoEffectsToComposition:mainCompositionInst size:size overlayerSize:size];//self.movieController.view.frame.size

    }

    //geting video name

    TempFile *loTemp = [[TempFile alloc] init];

    loTemp = [mallVideoArray lastObject];



    // 4 - Get path

    TempFile *mnewtemp = [[TempFile alloc] init];

    mnewtemp.mTemp_videoName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Video_%d.m4v",loTemp.mTemp_Key+1];

    [[Database sharedDBDetails] insertNewRowWithData:mnewtemp forTable:kvideoTable];

    NSString *myPathDocs =  [kDocument_Path stringByAppendingPathComponent:

                             [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Video/Video_%d.m4v",loTemp.mTemp_Key+1]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs];



    // 5 - Create exporter

    AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition

                                                                      presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];

    exporter.outputURL=url;

    exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;//@"com.apple.quicktime-movie";AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie

    exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;

    exporter.videoComposition = mainCompositionInst;

    [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{

        int exportStatus = exporter.status;

        switch (exportStatus)

        {

            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed: {NSError *exportError = exporter.error;NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed: %@", exportError);break;}

            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted: { NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted--"); break;}

            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusUnknown: { NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusUnknown"); break;}

            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusExporting: { NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusExporting"); break;}

            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled: { NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled"); break;}

            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting:{NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting"); break;}

            default: { NSLog (@"didn't get export status"); break;}

        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [self exportDidFinish:exporter];

        });

    }];

}

- (void)exportDidFinish:(AVAssetExportSession*)session

{

    [losaveView removeFromSuperview];

    if (session.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted)

    {

        NSURL *outputURL = session.outputURL;

        ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

        if ([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:outputURL]) {

            [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:outputURL completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                    if (error)

                    {

                        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Video Saving Failed"

                                                                       delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

                        [alert show];

                    }

                    else

                    {

                        self.mallVideoArray = [[[Database sharedDBDetails] getAllUserDetails:kvideoTable] mutableCopy];

                        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Video Saved" message:@"Saved To Photo Album"

                                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

                        [alert show];

                    }

                });

            }];

        }

    }

}
```

When I read docs it was written there that  [`exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler is a block that is invoked when writing is complete or in the event of writing failure`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetExportSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html).So if it is a failure then also it should call.Is there anything wrong with the code or am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you setting the delegate ?

Comment: Which delegate you are referring to?I have not set any?please suggest.

Comment: My mistake - there is no delegate. Put a breakpoint in the block and log value of export to check status.